# NetLogo error in BehaviorSearch optimization: error caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: netlogo, behaviorsearch

I developed a NetLogo model with the following setup

[image]

And I'm trying to run BehaviorSearch optimization like this:

[image]

The final measure is the average euclidean distance of the network:

```
sqrt ( ( centroid-x - max ( [xcor] of turtles )) ^ 2 + ( centroid-y - max ( [ycor] of turtles )) ^ 2 )
```

The code uses the following extensions [ py nw arduino csv matrix ]

But I get the error

```
Unexpected exception caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Looks like something was not defined, But I can't find it.

Any ideas what can be wrong ?

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, Java 1.8 properly configured, I updated to 1.11. However, when I click Load parameter ranges from model interface, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved [here](https://github.com/NetLogo/behaviorsearch/issues/5#issuecomment-1191702020):

> In the `app/` folder of your NetLogo install, find and open the `Behaviorsearch.cfg` file in a text editor. In the `[JVMOptions]` section add a line with `-Dorg.nlogo.preferHeadless=true`.